# Access more Business unity not works in Package in my case

Tags: marketingcloudapi, installedpackage

I have created a package in: **SETUP>
INSTALLED PACKAGES** For a business unit, I perform load tests at
data extension with Postman and it works, when I modify the package in **ACCESS>** and allow
access to another business unit, I test and it doesn't work.

Is it possible to modify the access, to a package already created?

Comment: what does your token call look like, are you passing account_id?

Comment: Yes, I pass the account_id, when I do insert with permissions to one Business Unit, it works, I insert data. When I add access to another business unit, the package stops making the insert that was already working